# how to create a small version of an image and display in original size when clicked in WebView?

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview

I am writing an application that loads up with local html pages. 
My html pages include some images as well , I want to show these images in a custom size in default (say 400px * 200px) , and displays in original size when user clicked in .

For example this is my image tag in html doc:

```
<img src="exclamation.png" 
alt="alt"
style="width:20px;height:20px;vertical-
align:middle;padding-left:5px">
```

What changes I must make to achieve the approach ?

Comment: that does not work @Reshma

Answer (score 0):

Check this solution

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/01/06/23/13/snow-crystals-1959292_960_720.jpg" id="abc"
alt="alt"
style="width:20px;height:20px;vertical-
align:middle;padding-left:5px" >
<script>
$("#abc").click(function(){
    $("#abc").attr("style","width:200px;height:200px;vertical-"+
"align:middle;padding-left:5px");
});
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for your feedback , how can I add this code to my WebView , i meant how i must use jquery in my webview ? can you explain a little bit

Comment: in your view page itself you can add a script tag. <script> </script> .Check the updated code

Comment: thanks, but that does not work , i copy whole code of yours and past to my html doc,even i enable javascript in my webView

Comment: @ShahinSoft have you enabled Javascript for webview like this:  WebView view =(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
    WebSettings settings = view.getSettings();
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

Comment: @Sanil yes i did it